# Firebase your realtime database has insecure rules warning

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a website that uses Firebase Realtime Database. It usually sends me e-mail about insecure rules warning. I searched about this here and Firebase Documantation, but when I write other rules, it gives me such error:

> Error saving rules - Line 10: String can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

```
{
  // Allow anyone to read data, but only authenticated content owners can
  // make changes to their data

  "rules": {
    "some_path/${uid}": {
      ".read": true,
      // or ".read": "auth.uid != null" for only authenticated users
      ".write": "request.auth.uid == uid"
    } SHOWS ME ERROR IS HERE.
  } 
}
```

I am using this rules for now:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
      ".write": false
  }
}
```

[image]

here is one picture that I try one of other rules called Mixed public and private access.

I will be very glad if anyone can help me.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the error message in the Firebase console?

Comment: In the rule below it is not giving an error, but after I publish that rule I cannot get any data from Realtime Database.

Comment: You didn't apply the change from @sarthak's answer, which is definitely a mistake in your rules.

Comment: I tried @sarthak's answer again yesterday, and it accepted. I got an insecure rules e-mail again and now it says:
 We've identified the following issues with your security rules:
any user can read your entire database

Comment: I am very new in Firebase, I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am sorry about this.

Comment: That means you're still granting read access at the root, which is an anti-pattern. Consider granting read access on `some_path`.

Comment: You tried a lot, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax does not seem correct to refer to a child resource, check below syntax to achieve the desired effect

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: it gives this error message now:
Error saving rules - Line 8: Unexpected EOF.